WMS with white background
I have some WMS that come out as a white overlay. I can see the polygons but it "blocks" the background map.Example:

https://ext-geodata-nationella.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/services/LST/lst_lst_riksintressen_4/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

add transparent=true to the request

So, what would my URL look like in the end? Do I need a & sign in there?

Note according to the specification it should be transparent=TRUE.  Values are case sensitive.

I suspect the issue is that by default QGIS has selected an Image Encoding format that doesn't support transparency.  You should change this to say PNG

@nmtoken - only a really picky server would require upper case
